# Getting "DomainArgumentValidationException: Can not be null" while junit test

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Well it's look like I face the trouble which I cant solve by myself. Here the story: I have a task in which I should learn mockito framework and test couple methods. Use in memory database is not allowed.

In OrderDaoImpl class right here `return new Order(resultSet.getString(name));`
I get `DomainArgumentValidationException: Can not be null`.

Look at constructor of Order:

```
public class Order {

private String name;
private Set<Good> goods = new HashSet<>();

public Order(String name) {
    Util.assertValidName(name);
    this.name = name;
}

setters, getters...
```

If I understand correctly `new Order()` object must have proper name otherwise he can't be created. Name cannot be null. And that is why I have this headache.

How can I make resultSet passed the String in `new Order(resultSet.getString(name)` here?

If I wrong in my conclusions help me understand what is going on here and how to make it right.

Here my tested method:

```
class OrderDaoImpl {

    private DaoFactory daoFactory = new DaoFactory();

    Order retrieveByName(String name) throws Exception {
        String sql = "select * from orders where name = ?;";

        try (Connection connection = daoFactory.getConnection();
                PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            preparedStatement.setString(1, name);
            preparedStatement.execute();
            ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.getResultSet();
            resultSet.next();
            return new Order(resultSet.getString(name));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
    } 
}
```

Here my junit test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class OrderDaoImplTest {

    @InjectMocks
    OrderDaoImpl orderDao = new OrderDaoImpl();

    @Mock
    DaoFactory mockDaoFactory;

    @Mock
    Connection mockConnection;

    @Mock
    PreparedStatement mockPreparedStatement;

    @Mock
    ResultSet mockResultSet;

    @Test
    public void testRetrieveByName() throws Exception {
        // Set Up
        String sql = "select * from orders where name = ?;";
        String orderName = "Test";

        Answer<String> answer = new Answer<String>() {
            public String answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                String string = invocation.getArgumentAt(0, String.class);
                return string;
            }
        };

        // Mock expectations
        when(mockDaoFactory.getConnection()).thenReturn(mockConnection);
        when(mockConnection.prepareStatement(sql)).thenReturn(mockPreparedStatement);
        doNothing().when(mockPreparedStatement).setString(1, cathedraName);
        when(mockPreparedStatement.execute()).thenReturn(true);
        when(mockPreparedStatement.getResultSet()).thenReturn(mockResultSet);
        when(mockResultSet.next()).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(false);
        when(mockResultSet.getString(orderName)).thenAnswer(answer);

        // Execute the method being tested
        orderDao.retrieveByName(orderName);

        // Validation
        assertThat(orderDao.retrieveByName(orderName), is(new Order(orderName)));

        verify(mockDaoFactory, times(1)).getConnection();
        verify(mockConnection, times(1)).prepareStatement(sql);
        verify(mockPreparedStatement, times(1)).setString(1, orderName);
        verify(mockPreparedStatement, times(1)).execute();
        verify(mockPreparedStatement, times(1)).getResultSet();
        verify(mockResultSet, times(1)).next();
        verify(mockResultSet, times(1)).getString(orderName);
    }

}
```

Comment: if you put a breakpoint insside the Answer impl method.. does it stop?

Comment: @Maciej Kowalski no

Comment: what mockito version you are using and from what package is MockitoJUnitRunner?

Comment: Mockito 1.10.19   org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner

Comment: and mockito version?

Comment: I have used same version and same code (resultSet return "Test").. it works.. are you sure this all the code that is involved?

Comment: Mockito 2.                                                                                                     I updated my post upsters, look at constructor of Order. The problem is in name validation. Name cannot be null.

Comment: new Order(resultSet.getString(name)); Is resultSet a mockito proxy here?

Comment: I dont understand this question, please explain what do you mean?

Comment: in the debug mode you have inspect what is the instance under that reference

Comment: Is resultSet a mockito proxy here? Yes